# Decode URL via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to write a small extension for Google Chrome to decode an encoded URL that's displayed on the Site. I wrote the core method in Java some time ago and tried to convert it to JavaScript

```
function decodeURL(Encoded) {
var Length = Encoded.length;
var Counter = 0;
var Character;
var Decoded = "";
for (Counter = 0; Counter < Length; Counter++) {
    Character = Encoded.charAt(Counter);
    if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 70) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "/";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 51 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 65) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += ":";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 49) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "!";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 50) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "\"";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 51) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "#";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 52) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "$";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 53) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "%";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 51 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 68) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "=";
    } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 51 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 70) {
        Counter += 2;
        Decoded += "?";
    } else {
        Decoded += Character;
    }
return Decoded;
```

}
    }

Instead of an decoded URL it returns nothing (No errors and no String)
If anyone had an idea where the error might be, I'd be thankful.

Comment: i bet that `Encoded.length == 0` - is it?

Comment: Doesn't encodeURIComponent / decodeURIComponent work for this?

Comment: JavaScript has the native decode/encode functions. Would you be considering using them? [JavaScript decodeURIComponent() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the build-in functions of JS.
[encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

```
decodeURI("https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B");
```

Return "[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_шеллы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B)"

So no need to create your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Move your return outside for loop :

```
function decodeURL(Encoded) {
    var Length = Encoded.length;
    var Character;
    var Decoded = "";
    for (var Counter = 0; Counter < Length; Counter++) {
        Character = Encoded.charAt(Counter);
        if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 70) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "/";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 51 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 65) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += ":";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 49) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "!";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 50) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "\"";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 51) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "#";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 52) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "$";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 50 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 53) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "%";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 51 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 68) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "=";
        } else if (Character === 37 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 1) === 51 && Encoded.charAt(Counter + 2) === 70) {
            Counter += 2;
            Decoded += "?";
        } else {
            Decoded += Character;
        }

    }
    return Decoded;
}
console.log(decodeURL("???$$$?"));
```